# Navigation Drawer with NativeScript

Tags: nativescript

I'd like create a type of sidemenu with NativeScript, but I don't know how.
How to create a Navigation Drawer with NativeScript? 
Exists any module what can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no Drawer for now, but it's in the working AFAIK.

Meanwhile, you can check the official repo for NativeScript.
https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/tree/master/apps/TelerikNEXT

Check the TelerikNext app.

Answer (score 2):

Telerik announced [Telerik UI for Nativescript](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/welcome-to-telerik-ui-for-nativescript) as a plugin today.
The plugin now contains side drawer and data visualization tools. It's a commercial product but (only) the side drawer function inside it is free.

You can refer to [this doc](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/getting-started) for detail information.

Comment: Telerik has changed their regulatories and moved from a free (`nativescript-telerik-ui`) and pro version (`nativescript-telerik-ui-pro`) to `nativescript-pro-ui` which offers all those widgets for free: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/migration

Answer (score 2):

The drawer is here. Check out TJ Vantoll's boilerplate project to get you started...

https://github.com/tjvantoll/nativescript-template-drawer

Or a TypeScript version of that same template from Ignacio Fuentes...

https://github.com/ignaciofuentes/nativescript-template-drawer-ts

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how to create an animated drawer menu with NativeScript 1.3 (which added an animation framework): https://github.com/emiloberg/nativescript-animated-sidebar-menu-example

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's yet available I think you need to create your own module as a view and do your own navigation (open, close).

However right out of the box I haven't found anything else in their docs.

The other thing I tried is adding a button in the header, and still I only managed to change the color of the header so I think you need to wait some more time to do these simple stuff.

Ref : I'm developing a demo app based on [Buxfer](https://buxfer.com) and NativeScript.

Source Code: https://github.com/chehabz/Buxfer-NativeScript

Answer (score 0):

**I am uploading my working code. It is in Nativescript + Angular 2**

drawer.html

```
<RadSideDrawer [drawerLocation]="currentLocation" [transition]="sideDrawerTransition"tkExampleTitle tkToggleNavButton>
<StackLayout tkDrawerContent class="sideStackLayout">
    <StackLayout class="sideTitleStackLayout">
        <Label text="Navigation Menu"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout class="sideStackLayout">
        <Label text="Primary" class="sideLabel sideLightGrayLabel"></Label>
        <Label text="Social" class="sideLabel"></Label>
        <Label text="Promotions" class="sideLabel"></Label>
        <Label text="Labels" class="sideLabel sideLightGrayLabel"></Label>
        <Label text="Important" class="sideLabel"></Label>
        <Label text="Starred" class="sideLabel"></Label>
        <Label text="Sent Mail" class="sideLabel"></Label>
        <Label text="Drafts" class="sideLabel"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
<StackLayout tkMainContent>
    <Label [text]="mainContentText" textWrap="true" class="drawerContentText"></Label>
    <Button text="OPEN DRAWER" (tap)=openDrawer()></Button>
</StackLayout>
```

drawer.component.ts

```
import {Component , OnInit, Input,ElementRef, ViewChild,ChangeDetectionStrategy,ChangeDetectorRef} from "@angular/core";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { Page } from "ui/page";
import {View} from "ui/core/view";
import {Label} from "ui/label";
import {RadSideDrawerComponent, SideDrawerType} from 'nativescript-telerik-ui/sidedrawer/angular';
import {DrawerTransitionBase, SlideInOnTopTransition} from 'nativescript-telerik-ui/sidedrawer';
import * as sideDrawerModule from 'nativescript-telerik-ui/sidedrawer/';

@Component({
   selector: "hello",
   templateUrl: "shared/hello/app.hello.html",
   styleUrls: ["shared/hello/hello.css", "css/app-common.css"],
})
export class HelloComponent implements OnInit{

private _currentNotification: string;
private _sideDrawerTransition: sideDrawerModule.DrawerTransitionBase;

constructor(private _page: Page, private _changeDetectionRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    this._page.on("loaded", this.onLoaded, this);
}

@ViewChild(RadSideDrawerComponent) public drawerComponent: RadSideDrawerComponent;
private drawer: SideDrawerType;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.drawer = this.drawerComponent.sideDrawer;
    this._changeDetectionRef.detectChanges();
}

ngOnInit() {

}

public onLoaded(args) {
    this._sideDrawerTransition = new sideDrawerModule.PushTransition();
}

public get sideDrawerTransition(): sideDrawerModule.DrawerTransitionBase {
    return this._sideDrawerTransition;
}

public get currentNotification(): string {
    return this._currentNotification;
}

public openDrawer() {
    console.log("openDrawer");
    this.drawer.showDrawer();
}

public onDrawerOpening() {
    console.log("Drawer opening");
    this._currentNotification = "Drawer opening";
}

public onDrawerOpened() {
    console.log("Drawer opened");
    this._currentNotification = "Drawer opened";
}

public onDrawerClosing() {
    console.log("Drawer closing");
    this._currentNotification = "Drawer closing";
}

public onDrawerClosed() {
    console.log("Drawer closed");
    this._currentNotification = "Drawer closed";
}
}
```

Don't forget to import globally in app.module.ts below:

```
import { SIDEDRAWER_DIRECTIVES } from "nativescript-telerik-ui/sidedrawer/angular";
```

and in declarations array  add SIDEDRAWER_DIRECTIVES:

```
declarations: [
SIDEDRAWER_DIRECTIVES,
AppComponent,
...navigatableComponents
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this: https://www.nativescript.org/blog/using-cross-platform-native-sidedrawer-component-in-nativescript

> They now have the RadSideDrawer component 
>   http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/NativeScript/SideDrawer/overview

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer, especially the part "Provide context for links".